# PHP email sending issue with validated fields

Tags: php

I am facing an issue, I have successfully validated the input and required fields in my form. But if the user Submits the form, no matter if the fields are empty; it shows the error message with fields but also send the empty email.

I believe there is just a simple tweak that needs to be done. But I am lost. Please look into the below code I have:

```
<?php
$nameErr = $snameErr = $emailErr = $ownerNameErr = $ownerNatErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $sname = $regAddress = $email = $gender = $comment = $ownerName = $ownerNat = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
   if (empty($_POST["name"]))
     {$nameErr = "Name is required";}
   else
     {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
       {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
       }
     }

if (empty($_POST["sname"]))
     {$snameErr = "Company Second Name is required";}
   else
     {
     $sname = test_input($_POST["sname"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$sname))
       {
       $snameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
       }
     }

          extract($_POST);

     $to="example@example.com";
    $subject="Subject";
$body="<table width='100%' cellspacing='10' cellpadding='0'>
    <tr>
            <td style='color:blue;font-weight:bold;margin-left:500px;font-size:20px;' colspan='3'>My Form</td>
    </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>$name</td>
  </tr>

<tr>
    <td>Second Choice</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>$sname</td>
  </tr>

</table>";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: MySite '."\r\n";
/*$headers .= 'Reply-To:'."$textfield5"."\r\n";*/



if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers))
{


       $msg = "Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you soon.";
    /*$msg= "Successfully Sent";*/
}
else
{
    $msg= "msg not sent";
}

}

function test_input($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}
?>
```

HTML Part

```
<span class="error">* <?php echo $ownerNatErr;?></span>
   <br><br>

   E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>

   input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Information">
```

Any help/Suggestion is highly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: you are trying this on localhost or live server?

Comment: Please don't use `extract($_POST)`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19740597/1561072

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check the parameters for errors and set some error messages but your code calls `mail` anyway, even if you found an error.

You might want to add some conditions:

```
if($snameErr === '' && $nameErr === '' ...) {
  // call mail here, check whether it was successful and
  // tell the user about it
} else {
  // show error message or something else
}
```

By the way, I guess your code is vulnerable because you use `extract($_POST)`. An attacker might inject arbitrary variables and can therefore bypass your checks.

Comment: shouldn't the first line of your code snippet contain `!==` instead of `==`

Comment: @ChristianGärtner No, because non-empty messages indicate errors. So this example would call `mail` if no errors were detected. But you are correct somehow, I meant `===`.

Comment: Ah snap. I haven't read carefully enough. I thought you were checking the $sName etc. variables.

Comment: @just lerning: Thank you for your reply. It worked exactly as required.

Comment: @MuhammadI You're welcome, but - please - don't use `extract` in this case :)

Comment: Ahh...Its working but not perfect. On some hits the browser keeps on waiting whereas the email has been sent. Anotner issue: Validation is perfect but the message is not shown upon success ot failure...

Comment: I cannot say what's wrong as I don't know your code. The code you posted does not seem to contain anything that could cause this.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I just need to display the seccess/failure message atleast.. It is only sending email upon validation... but msg not displayed is strange. Please note that this condition is under the very first line of code: if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
....  the email check is not independent.. please look into it.

Comment: When do you set `$ownerNatErr` and `$emailErr`? Those are the only messages your code shows. `$msg` does not seem to be shown at all.

Comment: Dear, You are pointing about the HTML section (these are some of total fields I have shared here), I am printing $msg in PHP. I hope you have reviewed my code. So, Should I print $msg somewhere in HTML...?

Comment: Okay, if you are actually setting all message variables, you will just have to print them properly. But I cannot help you any further without seeing more code. If your problem persists, you might want to ask a new question on SO.

Comment: @Just Lerning: I have solved it. I got clue to print the $msg in HTML, which is successful.
Actually I wanted to print the msg globally on the page after the form submit, now I am able to print the $msg along with the other errors and fulfilled my requirement at least.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your validation is correct and I assume it does what you want, however: you do not prevent the `mail()` function from running if the validation fails.

You could do this:

```
if ($valid) {
    if (mail(...) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
 }
```

This `$valid` variable sou should set to `true` by default and in the if statement, where you set the error messages, you should the variable to `false`.

This way the mail function would be called if the input is valid only.

Cheers.